# ASP.NET Core 2.0+ - How to Keep Claims Up-to-date

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, claims-based-identity

I'm dabbling in ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to wrap my head around the identity authorization layer, and how to make sure that my cookie claims stay up-to-date.

I'm using the default Identity layer along with cookies. So, from what I've been able to debug through and figure out is when I log in, the framework fetches all of this data such as what roles they are in from a database and puts it into a cookie. Then, if I stop debugging and start it again, my cookie is still there so we don't have to go back to the database (from what I can tell). That is great and all, but...how do I keep my roles up to date. Meaning, what if a role changed in the database after the cookie was created.

For example, what if a manager goes in and changes the role that an employee has. How do we make sure that the employees cookie knows that a role changed and needs to re-fetch the user?

Comment: There is already a built-in mechanism for invalidating cookies which is the security stamp.  It should be updated with a new GUID in the database when roles are changed.  The security stamp is also stored in the cookie and at a predefined interval (default 30 mins) it'll be compared to the one in the database to check the cookies validity.

Answer (score 0):

First, the cookie is still there but only until your close your browser and open it again, the browser should remove the cookie as it rather doesn't have persistent expiry date set. In a default setup, your cookies don't have expiry date set so that they will be removed upon closing the browser.

Then, the token contents itself has the expiration date (independent of whether the cookie has one or not at the HTTP protocol level). When the token expires, the server treats a request as anonymous and forces the authentication flow. Thus, even if the browser has the very same cookie for a long time, sooner or later it will expire (token expiration date is one of configuration parameters at the server side).

The only real issue is then what happens when the user uses the site and their roles have been changed in the background - in a default setup new roles are not reflected until they relogin.

Comment: Are there any "best practices" for this? We would like to store the cookie beyond just the current session of the browser so that they don't have to log in every day. Knowing that we aren't the only app that wants this to happen, what do others do to maintain the data in the cookie?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet *Therefore, it is highly recommended to use non-persistent cookies for session management purposes, so that the session ID does not remain on the web client cache for long periods of time, from where an attacker can obtain it.* This is the security perspective. There's another - the usability perspective. You need to put one of them as more important by yourself.